# cURLnot working properly from PHP or CRON

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have nn.sh

```
#/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html
/usr/bin/curl 'https://web-api.wtnnip.com/app' \
  -H 'authority: web-api.wtnnip.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.wtnnip.com' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.wtnnip.com/ro-RO/non-professional' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

If I execute the file is working fine. If I copy cURL command and run in terminal, is working fine. Working fine means I receive the json collection.

But if I set crontab to run this file, or I run the file from PHP with exec or passthru I receive this error:

```
{"errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Invalid JSON payload in GraphQLAuth POST request.",
    "errorType" : "MalformedHttpRequestException"
  } ]
}
```

I also try to write a code and use the cURL directly from PHP, but I receive the same error.

How can I run this from cron or php? Thanks!

LE:

1. I use Debian 11, PHP 7.4 and cURL 7.74
2. I have bash as shell, I try with #/bin/bash as well

**SOLVED**

#!/bin/bash in first line

I forgot the exclamation mark.

Thanks to Ulrich Eckhardt for light!

Comment: I use Debian 11, PHP 7.4 and cURL 7.74

Comment: [edit] your Q to add that info.

Comment: What shell do you run in your terminal?

Comment: ps -p $$
PID TTY          TIME CMD2616 pts/0    00:00:00 bash

Comment: I change in nn.sh #/bin/bash but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/html || exit
```

If you want to try PHP, Try this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://web-api.wtnnip.com/app');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'authority' => 'web-api.wtnnip.com',
    'accept' => '*/*',
    'accept-language' => 'ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'origin' => 'https://www.wtnnip.com',
    'referer' => 'https://www.wtnnip.com/ro-RO/non-professional',
    'sec-ch-ua' => '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile' => '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform' => '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-dest' => 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode' => 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site' => 'same-site',
    'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip',
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```